# What is the correct way to represent this sum?

Tags: fourier-analysis

The summation of Fourier series of `Sin[x-x[i]]` at three location `x[1]` to `x[3]` is:

```
Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x - x[i]], x, 5], {i, 3}]
```

However, due to `x[i]` contains `x` literally, the result is not right

```
-((E^(I x) (-E^(I (-π)[1]) + E^(I π[1]) + 
     2 I E^(-I (-π)[1]) π + 2 I E^(-I π[1]) π))/(
  8 π)) + (
 E^(-I x) (E^(-I (-π)[1]) - E^(-I π[1]) + 
    2 I E^(I (-π)[1]) π + 2 I E^(I π[1]) π))/(
 8 π) - (
 E^(I x) (-E^(I (-π)[2]) + E^(I π[2]) + 
    2 I E^(-I (-π)[2]) π + 2 I E^(-I π[2]) π))/(
 8 π) + (
 E^(-I x) (E^(-I (-π)[2]) - E^(-I π[2]) + 
    2 I E^(I (-π)[2]) π + 2 I E^(I π[2]) π))/(
 8 π) - (
 E^(I x) (-E^(I (-π)[3]) + E^(I π[3]) + 
    2 I E^(-I (-π)[3]) π + 2 I E^(-I π[3]) π))/(
 8 π) + (
 E^(-I x) (E^(-I (-π)[3]) - E^(-I π[3]) + 
    2 I E^(I (-π)[3]) π + 2 I E^(I π[3]) π))/(
 8 π) + (-Cos[(-π)[1]] + Cos[π[1]])/(
 2 π) + (-Cos[(-π)[2]] + Cos[π[2]])/(
 2 π) + (-Cos[(-π)[3]] + Cos[π[3]])/(2 π) + (
 E^(-2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[1]] - Cos[π[1]] + 
    2 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(6 π) + (
 E^(-3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[1]] + Cos[π[1]] - 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[1]] + Cos[π[1]] + 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(-4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[1]] - Cos[π[1]] + 
    4 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(30 π) + (
 E^(-5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[1]] + Cos[π[1]] - 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[1]] + Cos[π[1]] + 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[1]] - Sin[π[1]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[1]] - Cos[π[1]] - 2 I Sin[(-π)[1]] + 
    2 I Sin[π[1]]))/(6 π) + (
 E^(4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[1]] - Cos[π[1]] - 4 I Sin[(-π)[1]] + 
    4 I Sin[π[1]]))/(30 π) + (
 E^(-2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[2]] - Cos[π[2]] + 
    2 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(6 π) + (
 E^(-3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[2]] + Cos[π[2]] - 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[2]] + Cos[π[2]] + 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(-4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[2]] - Cos[π[2]] + 
    4 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(30 π) + (
 E^(-5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[2]] + Cos[π[2]] - 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[2]] + Cos[π[2]] + 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[2]] - Sin[π[2]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[2]] - Cos[π[2]] - 2 I Sin[(-π)[2]] + 
    2 I Sin[π[2]]))/(6 π) + (
 E^(4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[2]] - Cos[π[2]] - 4 I Sin[(-π)[2]] + 
    4 I Sin[π[2]]))/(30 π) + (
 E^(-2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[3]] - Cos[π[3]] + 
    2 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(6 π) + (
 E^(-3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[3]] + Cos[π[3]] - 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(3 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[3]] + Cos[π[3]] + 
    3 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(16 π) + (
 E^(-4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[3]] - Cos[π[3]] + 
    4 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(30 π) + (
 E^(-5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[3]] + Cos[π[3]] - 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(5 I x) (-Cos[(-π)[3]] + Cos[π[3]] + 
    5 I (Sin[(-π)[3]] - Sin[π[3]])))/(48 π) + (
 E^(2 I x) (Cos[(-π)[3]] - Cos[π[3]] - 2 I Sin[(-π)[3]] + 
    2 I Sin[π[3]]))/(6 π) + (
 E^(4 I x) (Cos[(-π)[3]] - Cos[π[3]] - 4 I Sin[(-π)[3]] + 
    4 I Sin[π[3]]))/(30 π)
```

simply rename `x[i]` to `g[i]`, the result is

```
-(1/2) I E^(I x - I g[1]) + 1/2 I E^(-I x + I g[1]) - 
 1/2 I E^(I x - I g[2]) + 1/2 I E^(-I x + I g[2]) - 
 1/2 I E^(I x - I g[3]) + 1/2 I E^(-I x + I g[3])
```

Therefore, `Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x - g[i]], x, 5], {i, 3}] /. g -> x` can return the correct answer. However, this looks not elegant. Is there a better way or formal way to do this?

Comment: Nothing wrong with the latter - I'd argue using `x` and `x[...]` in such a construct is potentially confusing (and leads to unintended consequences as you've seen). You could also just use `x[0]` for the plain `x`, this keeps it consistent at gets the desired result (with `x[0]` in the place of `x`, o/c).

Comment: @ciao Because `x` is a variable, but `x[..]` is a constant value in `x`-axis. I think maybe it is a little easier to understand. If no better solution, I think changing `x[..]` to `magic[..]` also works for me ^_^

Comment: I'm with ciao, the solution you found is optimal, though I might have switched out the dummy variable and written `Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x0 - x[i]], x0, 5], {i, 3}] /. x0 -> x`

Comment: @JasonB Then, I think this question is solved.

Comment: @JasonB do you have any comment on the answer I started?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on comments from @JasonB and @ciao, the short answer for this problem is  **NO, there is no formal way to do this in Mathematica.**

Although `x` and `x[...]` are clearly **two different variables**, Mathematica sometime may trade them as somehow **related** variables or **one** variable. I do not know whether this assumption has any potential usage, but it looks like some kind of "bug" from my point of view.

As @ciao argued `x` and `x[...]` maybe "potentially confusing". This may be true. At least, it confused several functions in Mathematica like `FourierCoefficient`, `FourierSinSeries` and other similar functions.

Therefore, although in some case this representation may be easier to understand , the best way to avoid these problems may be **not to use** this kind of expression. Or, use the solution provided in the question and @JasonB's comments.

```
Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x0 - x[i]], x0, 5], {i, 3}] /. x0 -> x
```

or

```
 Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x - magic[i]], x, 5], {i, 3}] /. magic -> x
```

Comment: Another possible workaround would be to use `\[FormalX]` as either the expansion variable or the subscripted variable.

Comment: @J.M. aha, so `\[FormalX]` is the "formal" way to do this in MMA ^_^

Comment: I think the main thing is that `x` and `x[i]` aren't really separate entities to *Mathematica*.  Look at what you get when you run  `Table[x - x[3], {x, -2, 2}]`

Comment: @JasonB so what is the correct way to generate a group of variable? Any thought about this? I did something like `ithVar[var_, i_] := 
  ToExpression[ToString[var] <> "$" <> ToString[i]]; `, but it is kind of ugly.

Comment: No, I like this method, using `x[1]`, etc, you just can't then use `x` as an iteration variable in the same expression.  What I used to use before I knew this was something like `ToExpression["x" <> IntegerString[j]]`.   In your case, `Sum[FourierSeries[Sin[x - ToExpression["x" <> IntegerString[i]]], x, 
  5], {i, 3}]` works pretty well